# How to select first letter of each word of a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to select the first letter of each word of a string using regex but I faced a problem. I was able to select the first letter of first word using

```
/^\w?/igm
```

how do i modify this to select first letter of each word of a string ?

For an example i have string :
**I love dogs.**
I want the code to select I, L and D.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
\b(\w)
```

This will capture in group 1 the first letter of each word.

1. `\b` is a word boundary, it's a zero-length assertion that makes sure we don't have a word character before.
2. `(\w)` is a capture group `( )` that matches a word character `\w`.

So we are matching a word character (and save it in group 1) that is not preceeded by another word character (ie. The first character of a word)

Comment: thanks , it worked but can you explain me how this works ?